# How do I resolve "missing spellcheck service" when running Flutter tests in a Linux CI environment?

Tags: linux, flutter, continuous-integration, spell-checking, flutter-3.10

I have added `SpellCheckConfiguration` to various widgets in my Flutter app. I am on Flutter version 3.10.2. As part of this I have added tests to ensure spell checker is enabled. The tests looks like this:

```
    testWidgets('it should have a spellchecker enabled', (tester) async {
      tester.binding.platformDispatcher.nativeSpellCheckServiceDefinedTestValue = true;
      # other stuff
      expect(tester.widget<EditableText>(editableText).spellCheckConfiguration?.spellCheckEnabled, true);
    });
```

These tests run fine on a M1 mac and on another Linux developer laptop. For some reason these tests are failing in our Linux CI runner. This runner is using Ubuntu 22.

The error message I get is:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGET LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown:
Spell check was enabled with spellCheckConfiguration, but the current platform does not have a
supported spell check service, and none was provided. Consider disabling spell check for this
platform or passing a SpellCheckConfiguration with a specified spell check service.
```

I have tried to replicate my local setup in CI. I have installed Android Studio, Android SDK and Chrome in our CI runner. `flutter doctor` reports all of these as green. I have also tried to install spell check packages such as `aspell` and `hunspell`.

Do I need to simply install some other package to get this to work? (the Linux developer laptop has an extra 18k packages on it from `apt list` but I can't work through that entire list) Do I need to alter my tests to configure some kind of spell checking service?

Thank you!